# How to stop code once it reaches the tolerance number (for function approximation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, numeric, numerical-methods

So I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def g_of_x(x):
    return ((5/x**2)+3)

initial_guess = 3
for i in range(15):
    solution = g_of_x(initial_guess)
    initial_guess = solution
    iterations = i + 1
    print('iteration: %d, solution: %f' % (iterations, solution))
```

The code approximates the value of the function to its real solution on the interval [3,5]. If I need to implement a tolerance of 10^^(-5) so my code would stop when it hits that tolerance level, how would that be implemented?

In this code, the value at the 10th iteration is the correct answer, and I want my code to stop when it hits that value.

Comment: Well, how would you do it on paper? What's stopping you from implementing that logic in code?

Comment: On paper or visually, once I see that the 5th digit after the decimal point is fixed as the program runs more iterations, I know that that value is the first one that reaches that tolerance level.

Comment: Look for `break` (and `continue` for completeness) to, as it says, break out of loops.

Comment: @VoltStatic what about that do you not know how to do in Python?

Comment: I don't know how to compare if two solutions have the same number on the 5th decimal location of the number.

ex: 3.425988 and 3.425989 both have at the 5th decimal location. I don't know how to write a program to compare that.

Comment: you can implement tolerance using cmath.isclose(a,b,abs_tol=math.pow(10,-5))..make a copy of the initial_guess at the first. But i get your concern that the 5th value gets fixed after some iterations..

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I found using @Dexter0411 suggestion:

```
initial_guess = 3
previous_solution = 3
iterations = 0
while True:
    solution = g_of_x(previous_solution)
    if math.isclose(previous_solution,solution,abs_tol=math.pow(10,-5)) == True:
        previous_solution = solution
        iterations += 1
        print('iteration: %d, solution: %.10f' % (iterations, previous_solution))
        break
    else:
        previous_solution = solution
        iterations += 1
        print('iteration: %d, solution: %.10f' % (iterations, previous_solution))
```

As the last output will be the output that is within the tolerance level.